# Isolating load from both sides with N-channel MOSFETS

Tags: arduino, power, mosfet, switches

I am trying to isolate a load both from the +, and the ground side and tried the circuit in the schematic below. *I realize that the Q2 MOSFET should be p-channel, rather than n-channel*, but I only had n-channel MOSFETs laying around and gave it a shot. The resulting behavior is weird and defies my understanding. Therefore, I am asking for some help to understand what is going on.

[image]

**Notes on the schematic**

1. Vdd is 5V and connected to my benchtop power supply
2. Vcc is not really a fixed voltage, but a lead that was connected to three different options (Arduino digital pin, Arduino 5V, Power supply 5V)
3. Arduino and power supply grounds are shared, and the Arduino's Vin comes from the power supply's 5V line.
4. The load is a large inductor

**Behavior description**

- When powering the circuit, about 0.5W are dissipated even if the Vcc line is set to ground.
- If Vcc is set to the Arduino's high digital pin, the current flowing through the circuit increases slightly but does not come even close to what it should be (150 mA, vs the expected 650 mA).
- If Vcc is set to Arduino's 5V line, the current through the circuit jumps to 550 mA, and the load was also dissipating more.
- If Vcc is set directly to the power supply's 5V, the current draw reaches the nominal value.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Your question title appears to have nothing to do with the question. What mosfetS are being used? And is Q2 source-drain correct? You also refer to 0.5W dissipated but then start referring to 150mA and 650mA. These are disparate comparisons and don't give us anything to work with. It would also help if you gave us the inductor's resistance.

Comment: _"If Vcc is set to the Arduino's high digital pin, the current flowing through the circuit increases slightly but does not come even close to what it should be (150 mA, vs the expected 650 mA)."_ - What was the voltage from Vcc to Ground in this condition? Which MOSFETs did you use? Please show us a photo of the complete circuit.

Comment: Give up on what you are trying to do and just control the basic current with Vgs > 1x to 2x  Vgs(th) and RdsOn  << load ok? learn the basic characteristics!

Comment: WIth the gate of Q1 grounded, Q1 should be off, and very little current should flow (assuming an enhancement mode MOSFET). I second DKNguyen's concern that you might have pins mixed up.

Comment: Your "behavior description " is quite confusing. Also, you need to bootstrap Q2 for it to turn on fully. Otherwise, it will drop a lot of voltage and get hot.